# How to read from .rc file in vc++?

Tags: c++, resources

I'm new to vc++, i have created a resource file and i need to read the file from my vc++ code. Is there any api available to read rc files. can anyone help me.

Comment: `.rc` file is a normal text file. But you almost never need to read/parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about Windows development here, you generally don't operate on a raw textual `.rc` file - you compile it in with your executable code then load the compiled resources based on what you're loading, like `LoadString` or `LoadImage` or `LoadMenu`.  You would also put your dialog templates in there.  And there are also functions for finding resources generically and accessing them in a more raw form if you need.